# Windows 10 PC cannot detect certain folders from my Android phone

Tags: windows-explorer, filesystems, android, file-transfer, sd-card

I am trying to upload files from my Android (Huawei P9 Lite) phone onto my PC.

So, I plug in my phone,
[image: a]

Click on the device,

[image: a]

And then click on the SD card (as that's where the files are that I want to upload).

[image]

There is just one small problem...

The files "azrecorderfree", "inshot", "smartvoicerecorder", and "WhatsApp1" are all actually folders, and not files. When on the phone, I can open the folder without problem and can successfully access, read, and modify all the files inside the folder.

Changing the name of the "file" on the computer will also change the folder name on the mobile phone, while keeping the contents inside the folder.

Why is my computer displaying these four folders as files, and how can I make it successfully display them as folders?

Here are the SD card properties:
[image]

Comment: At a guess, perhaps these are not actually folders but [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

Comment: @Anaksunaman They appear as folders on my Phone.

Comment: My experience is that symbolic links are often displayed by the native operating system as the type of object they meant to represent/link to.

Comment: @Anaksunaman But how would I allow my PC to view the actual files?